# I am using angular to create web API but unfortunately i am facing this issue so please anyone guide me to resolve this issue

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

```
 ERROR in node_modules/@angular/common/http/http.d.ts:2801:22 
- error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class

2801 export declare class HttpClientModule 

while my code is 
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BankAccountComponent } from './bank-account/bank-account.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
AppComponent,
BankAccountComponent
],
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule, 
ReactiveFormsModule,
HttpClientModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

when i  entered HttpClientModule in my import area then this error display if i remove HttpClientModule then this error disappear. how can i resolve this error please guide me for that.thank you.

Comment: what is  export declare class HttpClientModule

Comment: sir i am beginner i can not understand your question so would you live to explain it please

Comment: can you post the error and original code separately

Comment: Make sure all the @angular packages are pinned at the same version.
That error usually happens when you have different angular packages versions around

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue. I don't know which version of Angular you are using on your project.

What I did was, I just updated my Angular CLI to the latest version by running this command:

```
npm update angular-cli -g
```

Then I created a new project and moved all the files to here and build, now no errors on HttpClientModule.
its a weird error I suddently got and now gone.